# JMS message not delivered until receiver times out

Tags: jms, message-queue

In my application, I am using MDBs to listen to messages from a queue and then posting a request message to another queue. This posting of message to another queue happens within the MDB. Then I wait for a response using recieve method with a timeout of 20 secs. What happens now is that the request message I post to the queue is not getting delivered for 20 secs.
The message gets delivered after 20 secs but by that time the receive method returns and we are not able to process the response we receive for our request.

I am not using transacted sessions for posting the message to the queue.
Please tell me why the message is not getting delivered till the timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

Using an MDB suggests that you are running within a Java EE server of some sort. Are you sure you do not have a distributed (JTA) transaction enabled for your MDB and JMS session? That would explain the request message not getting delivered until your method returns. There can be a JTA transaction enabled even though the session transaction is specified to false.

This [blog post](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.se/2006/08/jms-requestreply-from-ejb.html) covers this case pretty good, even though it's a bit old.

The short answer is to use a UserTransaction and commit the request transaction before starting to wait for a reply.